# How to allow specific ip to access subdirectory site with htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I need to allow only specific IPs to access my site (www.domain.com/mysite). In htaccess I put this code:

```
ErrorDocument 403 /error403.html
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 1.1.1.1
```

But it looks for error403.html in root folder instead of "mysite" folder. I tried with ErrorDocument 403 /mysite/error403.html still doesn't work. I tried with RewriteBase /mysite also doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

So you're telling apache to *not allow access to everything in `/mysite`*, then you're telling apache to send any 403's (which is the result of attempting to access something in `/mysite`) to load a page **in `/mysute`**. So of course this isn't going to work. You're probably going to need to make an exception for `/mysite/error403.html`:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI ^/mysite/error403.html$ allow_ok

ErrorDocument 403 /mysite/error403.html
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 1.1.1.1
allow from env=allow_ok
```